# Goursat proof of Cauchy Integral Theorem assumption

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying the [Goursat proof of the Cauchy Integral Theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485803334)

It relies on the remark that the integrals $\int dz$ and $\int zdz$, taken along any closed contour are null.

I don't know how to prove that. I can imagine that $\int dz=0$ because when you return from where you went, the sum of all your trips should be null (it is not a very rigorous mathematical proof), but for $\int zdz$ it is much harder for me.

Can you help me to solve that problem?

Edit: we could use Cauchy's integral theorem for that but since it is exactly what we are looking to prove it doesn't make sense...

Comment: Do you know the theorem that $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$ depends only on the endpoints of $\gamma$ if  $f(z)$ is the derivative of an analytic function?

Comment: I knew that for real functions but I thought the goal of Cauchy's Theorem was to prove it for complex functions.

Comment: The goal of Cauchy's theorem is to prove this property for analytic functions at a point in the development of the theory of analytic functions when you don't yet know that every analytic function is the derivative of another analytic function. You then use the theorem as an important tool to prove that and many other important facts, e.g., that an analytic function has higher derivatives of all orders.

Comment: I can not contradict you, but it is not presented like this for example in Wikipedia or in most other resources.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem calculus applies to complex differentiable functions in a similar way to how it applies to real differentiable functions. To spell it out, if $f(z)$ is complex differentiable, and if $\gamma$ is a path from $a$ to $b$, then
$$ \int_\gamma f'(z) dz = f(b) - f(a).$$

In particular, if $\gamma$ is a *closed* path, then $\gamma$ starts and finishes at the same place, so the $a$ and $b$ in the equation above are the same point. So if $\gamma$ is a closed path, you have
$$ \oint_\gamma f'(z) dz = 0.$$

Now if you apply this result with the differentiable functions $f(z) = z$ and $f(z) = \frac 1 2 z^2$, you will be able to deduce that $\oint_\gamma 1 dz = 0$ and $\oint_\gamma z dz = 0$ along any closed path $\gamma$.

Comment: OK so Cauchy's integral theorem is only interesting for functions f(x) which we can prove that they are holomorphic but not that there exists a function F(x) such that F'(x) = f(x). It is very limited. And what is the theorem which prove that ∫f′(z)dz=f(b)−f(a), if not Cauchy's integral theorem?

Comment: The proof that $\int_\gamma f'(z) = f(b) - f(a)$ is a trivial consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus in real analysis: $\int_\gamma f'(z) dz = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} (f \circ \gamma)'(t) dt = (f\circ \gamma)(t_1) - (f\circ \gamma)(t_0) = f(b) - f(a)$.

Comment: @JeanPaul … and as for your first comment, I must disagree! I think Cauchy's integral theorem is very powerful! For example, one of the things you can prove using Cauchy's integral theorem is that **all** holomorphic functions $f$ can be written in the form $f(z) = F'(z)$, at least in small, local regions of the complex plane!

Comment: I guess you're right but for me your formula above is the most interesting result because it's simple and in practice I think that if we can prove that a function is holomorphic then we can most of the time find a function $F(z)$ such that $f(z) = F'(z)$. I think it would have been better to be clearer about that.

Comment: Okay, fair enough!

Comment: The paper you are reading is original research: I wouldn't expect it to contain motivation for the importance of Cauchy's theorem: Goursat's readers would have been well aware of that. What they would have been interested in is Goursat's delightfully simple proof of the theorem. If you want the motivation, look at any good book on Complex Analysis, e.g., Ahlfors. (Part of the motivation is that it helps in the proof that all analytic functions have power series expansions, so that your vague "most of the time" we can find an antiderivative becomes a general theorem).